# не находит функцию при использовании httprouter

Tags: golang

Хочу сделать роутинг через httprouter. Делаю так:

```
import (
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", Index)
    router.POST("/", Store)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
}

func Index(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request,  _ httprouter.Params)  {
    response.Header().Set("Content-type", "json")

    users := getAll()
    jsonResponse, _ := json.Marshal(users)

    responseData := map[string][]*User{
        "data": users,
    }

    jsonResponse, err := json.Marshal(responseData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    io.WriteString(response, string(jsonResponse))
}

func Store(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request,  _ httprouter.Params)  {
    jsonResponse, _ := json.Marshal("{success:true}")
    io.WriteString(response, string(jsonResponse))
}
```

но функции Index и Store не находит. выводится ошибка

```
# command-line-arguments
.\Main.go:21: undefined: getAll
.\Main.go:24: undefined: User
```

Comment: Приведите MCVE, т.к. пока текст ошибки довольно понятен - это неизвестные функции/переменные, т.к. они нигде не определены.

Comment: Небось `go run main.go` делаете и ожидаете, что остальные файлы в папке оно само найдёт?

Comment: да, а что, не должно?

Comment: @JonnyManowar См. ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы используете `go run`, вы должны указывать *все* файлы. `go run` работает по файлам:

```
$ go run main.go user.go foo.go
```

А лучше используйте `go build` и `go install`. Они работают как по файлам, так и по пакетам. Например:

```
$ ls
main.go user.go foo.go
$ go build
$ ls 
main main.go user.go foo.go
$ ./main
```