# Gorilla websocket example не видит файлы

Tags: golang

решил попробовать использовать websocket на go (нужно для backend части мобильного приложения).

Я познакомился с примером на `https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat`

создал такие же файлы с таким же содержимым в одной директории.

И пытаюсь запустить из терминала VS Code командной `go run main.go`

Он кидает ошибку

```
# command-line-arguments
.\main.go:26:9: undefined: newHub
.\main.go:30:3: undefined: serveWs
```

Почему он видит эти файлы?

(с GO первый раз знакомлюсь)

Comment: А вы пакет `github.com/gorilla/websocket` установили?

Comment: @zed да, командой go get github.com/gorilla/websocket, к тому же если бы он не использовался, он бы подчеркивался в vs code

Comment: @zed может он не в том месте лежит? Может он в C должен лежать в папке первого уровня?

Comment: А, понял: для go run надо указывать все файлы из пакета. Вот так работает: `go run main.go hub.go client.go` или просто `go build` и далее уже запускаете бинарник руками.

Comment: Ещё можно писать вот так (с точкой в конце) `go run .` тогда не надо перечислять все файлы пакета. [go run help](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program)

Comment: @zed спасибо, то что нужно

Comment: @zed а не подскажите еще по поводу работы чатов в Messengerах? Как это правильно (теоретически реализовать), свои последние догадки, я  написал в комментариях https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1102196/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%bf-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-websocket?noredirect=1#comment1898892_1102196. Можете опровергнуть мои домыслы или подтвердить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [не находит функцию при использовании httprouter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700286/%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-httprouter)